# Additional sections in collapsed topics when migrating moodle

Tags: php, plugins, moodle

I have migrated Moodle from 2.5.4 to 3.4 (in stages). I have downloaded the Collapsed Topic format (ver: 2017110300) from the moodle plugin directory for 3.4. I am using subpage activity under every section. While it has migrated all the content fine, it has the following issues,

1. All the sections have been migrated fine (along with the subpages, which have SCORM packages / files in them), however there has been additional sections created (Section 110, Section 114 etc.) which contain items under the subpages (from the initial sections).
2. Hiding those sections hides the section, but also the packages/files under the section and it is not visible from the subpage in initial sections as well.
3. Removing those sections removes the section, but also the packages/files under the section.

Also, migrated course does not have the limit to specify for topics in the course settings, while the new course has that option.

I cannot re-add those packages/files since those have some statistics associated with it. So, it is a kind of blocker and I am not able to proceed further. It seems to be a bug, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

So what exactly is the issue here.

If there are SCORM packages and files are appearing under a section you want to hide or remove, you can turn on editing and move those activities up into one of your other sections.

This will keep all the statistics associated with them. Please explain further if this does not solve the issue.

Comment: Actually, I have a collapsed topic (with 4 sections) and under each section I have a module (activity) called "subpage" (to organise activities). Each subpage has few SCORM activities / folders (will be visible only if the subpage is clicked). When adding activities to subpage it actually adds to a section within the subpage, however, that section is visible at the course level as well, so the items added under subpage is visible in the sections at a course level. So, if I hide/remove the section at a course level it hides/removes the activities as well, that is the issue.